# DataFrame apply/append a function that returns a dict to each row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-apply

I'm looking to apply `get_sentiment` to each row in a dataframe and have the returned dict append to that row. Is there a good way of doing this?

```py
def get_sentiment(txt: str) -> dict:
    response = client.detect_sentiment(Text=txt, LanguageCode='en')

    sentiment_data = dict()
    sentiment_data['Sentiment'] = response['Sentiment']
    sentiment_data['Sentiment_Score_Positive'] = response['SentimentScore']['Positive']
    sentiment_data['Sentiment_Score_Neutral'] = response['SentimentScore']['Neutral']
    sentiment_data['Sentiment_Score_Negative'] = response['SentimentScore']['Negative']
    return sentiment_data


def analyze_txt(df: DataFrame):
    df[] = df['Text'].apply(get_sentiment) #<- what I'm trying to do
```

Basically want the df to go from

| id | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | hello world |
| 2 | this is something here |

to

| id | Text | Sentiment | Sentiment_Score_Positive | Sentiment_Score_Neutral | Sentiment_Score_Negative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hello world | Neutral | .5 | .5 | .5 |
| 2 | this is something here | Neutral | .5 | .5 | .5 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you apply `get_sentiment` to the `Text` column, it returns a Series of dicts, so one way to get the desired output is to convert it to a list of dicts and construct a DataFrame with it; then `join` it to `df`:

```
new_df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['Text'].apply(get_sentiment).tolist()))
```

If `df` has a specific index that needs to be retained, you could assign it when constructing the DataFrame to be joined:

```
s = df['Text'].apply(get_sentiment)
new_df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=s.index))
```

A faster method maybe to simply map `get_sentiment` to the `Text` column values:

```
new_df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(map(get_sentiment, df['Text'].tolist())))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) looks like a viable option, too. To turn a list of dictionaries (or a list of lists that represent rows) into a dataframe, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html).

```py
df2 = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.Text.apply(get_sentiment))], axis=1)
```